# Annular Solar Eclipse - Adak Island, May 2012: Airfare help?

Tags: air-travel, alaska, events, eclipses

I want to take a flight to Adak island (or a ferry) for the [May 2012 solar eclipse](http://eclipse.gsfc.nasa.gov/SEanimate/SEanimate2001/SE2012May20A.GIF).

All the flights from CHI to ADK on alaskaair.com state them as fully booked. This is, most likely, due to many people trying to go see the eclipse? Is there a reason this airport, which [Wikipedia's entry for Adak island](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adak_Island#Transportation) states is, "unusually sophisticated" might not be offering flights to the island?

**Is anyone experienced in navigating the island chain on the South Western coast of Alaska, and can help me find an alternative route there?**

p.s., this may be off-topic, but if anyone's interested in putting together a group, visit my profile and send me an email.

Comment: Def not off topic, comes under event travel, see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/210/where-would-be-the-optimal-place-to-watch-the-nov-2012-solar-eclipse-from as another example :D

Comment: Random question - I've seen two totals, and will be aiming for the Nov 14 one, but an annular isn't a complete covering - is it still visually impressive?

Comment: From that same wiki page - "Alaska Airlines operates twice weekly 737-400 Combi passenger and cargo jet service from Anchorage. At present, flights operate each Sunday and Thursday (weather permitting)." - have you ensured you're choosing a date with flights actually running?

Comment: @MarkMayo I couldn't tell you. But, if you look at the link I posted for May 2012 solar eclipse, you'll probably find it's going to be *exceptionally* impressive.

Comment: Just curious, why not pick a closer location, like say, Zion National Park or Grand Canyon? I'm actually planning a trip there for that very eclipse myself... According to the maps, the eclipse is shorter by about 30 seconds, but otherwise, it seems like exactly the same thing, and who wouldn't want to see Zion?

Comment: any more luck with finding cheaper flights?

Comment: To be honest, I've had second thoughts. After seeing your post about the Nov. 2012 eclipse, I took a look at [some of the resources](http://xjubier.free.fr/en/site_pages/solar_eclipses/ASE_20120520_pg01.html) you posted, and am quite discouraged about the average cloud cover. How embarrassing would that be? Spend $4k, and get a cloudy, dark patch of afternoon to show for it?!?

Comment: Oh I've heard of several people having that happen. But it's a case of travelling there and hoping!

Comment: @MarkMayo couldn't go, but I'm going to [watch from home instead](http://eclipse2012.unm.edu/event_map.phtml). By the way, it looks like I made the [right call about Adak Island](http://www.wunderground.com/wundermap/?lat=51.88000107&lon=-176.65805054&zoom=8&pin=Adak%2c%20AK&type=hyb&rad=0&wxsn=0&svr=0&cams=0&sat=1&sat.num=1&sat.spd=25&sat.opa=85&sat.gtt1=109&sat.gtt2=108&sat.type=IR4&riv=0&mm=0&hur=0)

Comment: I was in Seattle, cloudy as :( But cheaper than a last minute flight to Arizona/New Mexico :)  I'll be at the November one tho!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a "wanted ad" not a question and, in any case, the event in question was years ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a little searching, there are still flights on a couple of days, if you're prepared to go to Vancouver first. It's not cheap, however:

http://www.kayak.co.uk/#flights/YVR-ADK/2012-05-17-flexible/2012-05-22-flexible

Much like the other reference, it appears to only have flights on Thursdays and Sundays.  Still, that's better than the once a week flight to and from Tonga I took from New Zealand ;)

EDIT:

Hey look at that, for a similar rate, you CAN get your flight from Chicago:

http://www.kayak.co.uk/#flights/CHI-ADK/2012-05-17-flexible/2012-05-22-flexible

Comment: I almost want to downvote you because that's **so incredibly expensive**! `:D` I could take a train for that!

Comment: Hey, don't blame me, blame the airlines.  At least now you know it's *possible* and you have a target to beat :)

Comment: I know the feeling tho, I was looking to book Santiago -> Easter Island flights for the last total a year in advance, had two travel agents on standby, and they went from £300 to £3000 overnight, a year in advance, solely because of the eclipse tourism.  Frustrating, these tour groups getting in the way of us freelancers ;)

Comment: Did you see the link I posted? It's at high noon on the international date line. There will never be an eclipse like this again for some time.

Comment: Agreed.  Plotting it on NASA: http://eclipse.gsfc.nasa.gov/SEplot/SEplot2001/SE2012May20A.GIF - it's indeed visible in Vancouver, but Adak would be so much cooler....

Comment: Hey look what I found:

[Flights from CHI to ANC](http://www.kayak.co.uk/#flights/ORD-ANC/2012-05-16-flexible/2012-05-20-flexible) are much cheaper. Now I just have to find a hunting enthusiast who would fly me in on their two seater....haha.

Answer (score 4):

A different option so seemed worthwhile putting as a separate answer:

http://www.kayak.co.uk/#flights/ANC-ADK/2012-05-17-flexible/2012-05-22-flexible

If you can get to Anchorage, it's .. well... also horrendously expensive, but if you can get a cheap way to Anchorage, it may save some.

Again, Sunday and Thursdays seem to be the only days flights are active on.

Comment: Looks like I may be getting closer: 

[Travel by cargo ship](http://wikitravel.org/en/Freighter_travel)

Comment: In that case: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/598/where-can-i-get-information-on-freighter-travel, http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/115/freight-travel-in-the-caribbean-can-it-be-done-is-it-cost-effective and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/558/is-there-a-boat-that-will-take-tourist-to-iceland-from-north-america